# How to call multiple classes of CSS in a single class?

Tags: html, css

I have made one button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn-custom btn btn-info" />
```

**CSS Code**

```
.btn-info {
  background-color: #6fb3e0!important;
  border-color: #6fb3e0;
}
.btn{padding:5px 10px}
.btn-custom{height:20px;}
```

I want to combine the style of `btn-custom` and `btn btn-info` in single class called `.btnCustom`.

In short I want the same result as when I try this:

```
<input type="button" class="btnCustom" />
```

Comment: what stops you including those classes in html??

Comment: <input type="button" class="btn-custom btn btn-info " />

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You will have another class to think about and remember. Your CSS will grow more complicated and be more bug-prone. Before long, you will be tempted to use a CSS pre-processor because its `extend` feature seems cool, a choice you will surely regret. But in addition, it will be harder for people reading your HTML to see what's going on. It's very much accepted practice in designing CSS to have smaller classes which each do one thing, exactly as `.btn-info` etc. do now, and specify multiple classes on HTML elements as a way of combining the behaviors of the classes.

Comment: I personally don't regret using preprocessors or using extends. They can be a great way to organise code (they are for me). Specifying multiple classes often works, but using BEM and hyper-targetting elements is another, which works particularly well for large scalable applications. There isn't just one way @torazaburo.

Comment: Yes, but different ways have different advantages and disadvantages. For example, ways which involve overly close coupling of HTML and CSS may gain a few microseconds in applying CSS, but mean that every time you blow your nose you're making changes in two places.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this -

```css
.btnCustom, .btn-info {
   background-color: #6fb3e0!important;
   border-color: #6fb3e0;
}
 .btnCustom ,.btn{
   padding:5px 10px;
 }
 .btnCustom ,.btn-custom{
   height:20px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btnCustom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now try to **[less](http://lesscss.org/)** css than define those class in one class as like this

Than try to this way

```
.btnCustom{
.btn();
.btn-info(); 
height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a preprocessor such as [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

```
.class1 {
  color: #333;
}

.class2 {
  @extend .class1;
  border-color: green;
}
```

Otherwise you have to stick to

```
<input type="button" class="btn-custom btn btn-info" />
```

Comment: No, he doesn't need a preprocessor. He needs basic CSS common sense.

Comment: He asked a question and I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some preprocessor like **less** or **sass**. (You can use the plain CSS too. Just use the Generated CSS code from SASS/SCSS code).

Using sass you can do it like:

HTML Code

```
<input type="button" class="btnCustom" />
```

SASS/SCSS Code

```
.btn-info {
  background-color: #6fb3e0!important;
  border-color: #6fb3e0;
}

.btn{
  padding:5px 10px
}

.btn-custom{
  @extend .btn;
  @extend .btn-info;
  height:20px;
}
```

Generated CSS Code after compiling the SASS/SCSS Code

```
.btn-info, .btn-custom {
  background-color: #6fb3e0!important;
  border-color: #6fb3e0;
}

.btn, .btn-custom{
  padding:5px 10px
}

.btn-custom{
  height:20px;
}
```

Of course if you don't want to use any preprocessor, you can use the CSS code generated after compilation directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Css like this,

```
.btnCustom, .btn-info {
   background-color: #6fb3e0!important;
   border-color: #6fb3e0;
}
 .btnCustom ,.btn{
   padding:5px 10px;
 }
 .btnCustom ,.btn-custom{
   height:20px;
 }
```

and Html

```
<input type="button" class="btn-custom btn btn-info" />
```

Its work in My Website.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually combine all the classes into a single selector like so;

```
.btn-custom.btn.btn-info {
}
```

That will only select elements with all those classes.

[You can read more about that selector at css-tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

Will that do what you want?

There are some good other answers. Using less or sass will likely do what you want.

[Be careful with how you use commas in your selectors.](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/rules_group_sel.htm)

Comment: That's not what he's asking.

Comment: @torazaburo It may do what he wanted, hence why i said "Will that do what you want?" - downvote was a bit rough